# set('isAdmin', true) just for a group ID's (not for all group's ID)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a bit of trouble setting a property for my controller based on admins' attributes. Right now I have a simple setup where a user can be an admin of a groupID.

MyDatabase:

```html
{
      "Admins" : {
        "AdminUser" : {
          "-McDwwt14uy-w3pxRwOO" : {
            "Confirm" : "yes",
            "Email" : "behnam.seven3@gmail.com",
            "GroupID" : "EN000111",
            "Name" : "Behnam Heidari",
            "Phone" : "+31686357000"
          }

      "Group" : {
        "-MVXRWD_yfVd7WBXy7EC" : {
          "ID" : "EN000111",
          "Name" : "ENGLISH20",
        },
        "-MVXdPmRer6ZTy_cchNp" : {
          "ID" : "EN000112",
          "Name" : "ENGLISH3",
        },
        "-MVYFXZyERYnx7EZZTBX" : {
          "ID" : "EN000113",
          "Name" : "ENGLISH4",
        }

      "Users" : {
        "aM8x8WjwuBNOQODQsqsNyXID6F83" : {
          "Source" : "android",
          "userGroupID" : "EN000111",
          "userName" : "behnam"
          "phoneNumber" : "+31686357000",
          "isAdmin" : "true",
        }
```

users:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppLifecycleListener.activityResumed();
}

private void getGroupUsersId() {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    refroot = mDatabase.child("Users");

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupUsersActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.show();
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                //create new user
                String value = "";

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (data.child("userGroupID").getValue().equals(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id")))) {
                        value = data.getKey().toString();
                        groupUserId.add(value);
                    }
                }
                for (String s : groupUserId) {
                    getGroupUsersInfo(s);
                }
                Log.i("value", value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(GroupUsersActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    refroot.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

setAdmins:

```
 private void getGroupUsersInfo(final String userId) {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    refroot = mDatabase.child("Users").child(userId);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GroupUsersActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.show();
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                //create new user
                UserNode userNode = new UserNode();
                userNode.setPhoneNumber(dataSnapshot.child("phoneNumber").getValue().toString());
                userNode.setUserName(dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString());
                userNode.setUserGroupID(dataSnapshot.child("userGroupID").getValue().toString());
                if (dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin").getValue().toString().equals("true"))
                        userNode.setIsAdmin(true);
                else
                    userNode.setIsAdmin(false);
                countinfo++;
                userNodeList.add(userNode);
                if (countinfo == groupUserId.size()) {
                    groupUsersAdapter = new GroupUsersAdapter(userNodeList, GroupUsersActivity.this);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                    groupUserrecycle.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    groupUserrecycle.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    groupUserrecycle.setAdapter(groupUsersAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
```

GET ADMIN INFO

```
 private void getAdminInfo() {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    refroot = mDatabase.child("Admins").child("AdminUser");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait");
    progressDialog.show();
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                //create new user
                String value = "";

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //value += data.child("Phone").getValue().toString();
                    adminList.add(data.child("Phone").getValue().toString());
                }
                Log.i("value", value);
            }
        }
```

The problem is this, an admin can be admins for all the groups. I want to change it that an admin of a GroupID just can be an admin for that's group, now an admin can be an admin for all the GroupIDs.

Comment: `java` != `javaScript` . I think so is not a `JavaScript` please change the tag to `java`

Comment: You've shared a lot of code in your question, and I'm not sure I understand the question. When you step through this code line by line in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you want it to do?